# Hibernate HQl to join two level tables

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I've four tables (t1,t2,t3,t4) and they have Primary keys(pk_) and foreign keys (fk_).
Table    columns

```
t1       pk_t1_id,fk_t3_id
t2       pk_t2_id,fk_pk_t1_id,fk_t4_id
t3       pk_t3_id
t4       pk_t4_id
```

Now i need to write HQL to get list by pk_t3_id,pk_t4_id.

I'm trying write HQL constraints and Restrictions to fetch data.

```
session.createCriteria(t2.class)
.createCriteria("t1.t4").add(Restrictions.eq("pk_t4_id",userId))
.createCriteria("tmSites").add(Restrictions.eq("pkSiteId", siteId));
```

can somebody correct me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

criteria is a less efficient way to join multiple table. So used name queries.